# Adding controls/usercontrols in Constructor/XAML VS adding controls in Loaded Event in WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I was wondering if there is any difference between adding some controls/usercontrols (that take time to initialize ) in XAML or constructor and in Loaded event of some window.

I have a window where I use same usercontrol thrice. This is a usercontrol and takes some time to initialize itself. This window takes around 5 - 7 seconds to initialize itself with all three usercontrols initialized. 
How should I approach adding them in window? 
( Someone suggested that adding control after window is loaded will allow window to load in faster way than adding them in XAML/Constructor of the window.)

I would like to have some suggestion from experts on this topic as I don't know much about this.

Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate downvote of some users, as they are expert on this topic. Please share your knowledge if you want to downvote this question. I really appreciate that. :) That will help me to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Why are the controls/user controls taking that long to load?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: @m-y - They are viewports (like we have in AutoCAD), I can't change them, because they are third party controls. So, I have to think workaroung for loading these usercontrols.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with deferring the loading of a window's content until after the window has been shown.  The event you probably want is `ContentRendered`, which tells you the window's handle has been created, and the window shown.

I would suggest wrapping your window's content in a single "view", say a `UserControl`, such that you only need to set the window's `Content` and be done with it, as opposed to imperatively injecting multiple controls.  It just makes things simpler.  In essence, make your view a user control, and treat the window as the host of your view.

None of this is likely to reduce the time required to populate your window, but at least you'll be able to show *something* while the content is processed, even if it's just an empty window with a wait cursor.

Also, look for any places where you perform expensive operations on the UI therad (e.g., in your views or view models), and consider replacing those with asynchronous operations.  You might find that you're able to load the UI faster than the underlying data, in which case you can display a more complete view with the appropriate wait/progress indicators until your data comes in.

Comment: I am loading these controls in Loaded event. Not directly in loaded event, but after loading is completed, I am using async methods to load these controls. This let's me perform other operations while these usercontrols are still loading on another thread. :)

Comment: You can't load user controls on a separate thread; they must be created and populated on the same thread that you will use to display them.